# New Intent not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent

why does the new intent work in the second part (inside the onTouchEvent) but not in the first part (update()). if i put it in the method update() (where i need it), it doesnt do anything. I put a log entry in it to see if it actually passes the if/then, and it does.

Update:

Ok its getting WEIRD now. I tried all 3 answers down here, but still wouldn't work. Untill my phone screen went off (using an android connected via usb). now when i turn it on again i see the new activity has started!

Update 2:
Tried it in an emulator and it does work normal! How is that possible?

```
class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private MainThread _thread;

public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);

        _thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
        setFocusable(true);
}

public void update() {


        if (deckPos >= 25) {
            Log.v("DEBUG", "finished");

            // --- DOESNT WORKS HERE ---
            Context context = getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScoreScreen.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            // ------------------

        }


    }


public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        synchronized (_thread.getSurfaceHolder()) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {


            // --- WORKS HERE ---
            Context context = getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScoreScreen.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            // ------------------

                touchX = (int) event.getX();
                touchY = (int) event.getY();
                touching = true;

                if (cardDispencer.contains(touchX, touchY)) {
                    holdingCard = true;
                }

                int t = returnTouchingCardGrid(touchX, touchY);

                if (t < gridIDs.length && gridIDs[t] == 0) {
                    gridIDs[t] = deck[deckPos];
                    deckPos++;
                    updateScore();
                }

            }

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                touchX = (int) event.getX();
                touchY = (int) event.getY();
            }

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                int t = returnTouchingCardGrid((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

                if (t < gridIDs.length && gridIDs[t] == 0 && holdingCard) {
                    gridIDs[t] = deck[deckPos];
                    deckPos++;
                    updateScore();
                }

                touching = false;
                holdingCard = false;

            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not calling yout update() method whenever you want...

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to like this

```
public void update() {

    if (deckPos >= 25) {
        Log.v("DEBUG", "finished");

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScoreScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

start activity with Intent , not with context variable. If you need more clarification how to call another activity using intent you can find nice tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html)

Comment: Have the intent start itself?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScoreScreen.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(your_current_activity.this, ScoreScreen.class)
startActivity(intent);
```